# Multiple log directories in a Kafka installation

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using an Apache Kafka broker on Ubuntu which runs as a Linux system service alongside Zookeeper Linux service. I know how to use a standalone Kafka Broker and it works great for our application however I lack some experience and knowledge of a Kafka Cluster.

Unfortunately we've experienced a server shutdown for the 2nd time this year and it affected the cluster so that cluster Id was changed and Kafka Service couldn't restart because of it. When changing cluster Id in meta.properties file didn't work I looked for a solution in StackOverflow and what I found was to delete the logs directory. However, as I mentioned before, this is the second time that a shutdown occurs and after deleting such directory and re-creating it my Kafka installation dir has 2 different log directories. They are named "logs-1" and "logs" because Kafka tries to create /logs/logs.log file each time it restarts so naturally each one of them contains different data (topics and configurations).

Question - is there a way to sync the 2 directories so that older data is not lost? using ZooKeeper maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka automatically replicates data, assuming you've configured it properly. You cannot sync directories across brokers since each broker doesn't need to share equal partitions. This is how data is distributed in the cluster.

Zookeeper doesn't sync Linux OS filesystems, and next major release of Kafka will completely remove dependency on it so I wouldn't spend time investigating that.

`log.dirs` are not automatically created. The admin should prepare each one with the necessary OS permissions and/or volume mounts. (Do use external disks for Kafka, do not share the OS volume, and especially not the volume with /var/log... This applies to most *nix admin operations)

The "logs-1" directory is simply partition 1 of the "logs" Kafka topic. Those directories store Kafka log *segments and indicies*. If/when you delete these, you're causing data loss...

Having 3 (or more) brokers, each with topics having `replication.factor=3` and `min.insync.replicas=2` is recommended for fault tolerance. This way, you could lose any one broker for a topic and clients continue to work without data loss.

Anything less than that, you're going to lose data and running `rm -rf` on the log.dirs is only to be ran as a last resort